# create a table from existing table with adding one extra field in the new one

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table archive as select * from EMP where 1=2;
```

I want to add extra field current date in archive table

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server..and one question related to plsql i need to create a table that has same field as EMP table in HR schema but with extra field in new table

Comment: Plsql is Oracle. And you use MS SQL Server?

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer not MS SQL server

Answer (score 0):

`where 1=2` will always be false thus returning 0 records. Anyway, you can get it work like below but `DATETIME` functions are RDBMS specific. `NOW()` will work only if it's `MySQL`

```
create table archive as
select *,NOW() as Create_date from EMP
```

Comment: create table archive as select * from EMP where 1=2; after that alter table command..-----alter table archive add curr_date date;